# MNIST random sample plotting is not working

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn, mnist

I am randomly sampling the [MNIST data set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MNIST_database), but it shows an error. Where am I doing wrong?

```
import sklearn
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml

mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784')
y = mnist.target
X = mnist.data.astype('float64')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 5)
ax = ax.flatten()
for i in range(10):
    im_idx = np.argwhere(y == str(i))[0]    # Pandas versions bug - it worked in PyCharm. {Kindly, what is an alternate way to fix it?}
    print(im_idx)
    plottable_image = np.reshape(X[im_idx], (28, 28))
    ax[i].imshow(plottable_image, cmap='gray_r')
```

The error shows:

> ValueError: Length of passed values is 1, index implies 70000.

Comment: What error? Please post a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting results because `np.argwhere(y == i)` returns an empty array and that is because you are trying to make a comparison between `y` which is filled with `string` values and `i` which is an `int`.

The following change will fix it:

```
im_idx = np.argwhere(y == str(i))[0]
```

Here is the cast to match the NumPy operations:

```
y = mnist.target.to_numpy()
X = mnist.data.astype('float64').to_numpy()
```

Comment: What is the error? please edit your original post with it and the updated piece of code.

Comment: I just ran your code again with my fix and it plots the images, edit your post with what you just did ran.

Comment: @antima99 you didn't change your line of code, the error still says `im_idx = np.argwhere(y == i)[0]`, please re-run it while casting `i` to `string` like my line.

Comment: thank you it worked.

Comment: @antima99 don't forget to upvote & tick the green v :)

Comment: please check it it shows this error again,

Comment: It is another error which is means you need to open a new question for it, it will be easier to understand too for both of us, please create a new question **with your updated code**

Comment: i cannot ask new question this week. i have crossed my limit for asking 3 questions. kindly help me out with this bug. i am updating my question , help me out

Comment: Ok ill look into it.

Comment: @antima99 For some reason, `X` & `y` are `pandas` objects instead of `numpy.array`, ill edit my answer with the updated cast.